# DragSortListView and AlertDialog?

Tags: android, listview, sorting, drag-and-drop

I have been trying to get this library:
https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview/

to work inside an AlertDialog. But I have has no success so far. Everything looks perfect but the drag and drop does not happen.

Any suggestion it can be done? If there is no way to do this inside a AlertDialog, is there a way to do this without using intents?

Here is my code:

```
public class FolderSorter
{
    Context parent;
    ArrayList<String> lists;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    public FolderSorter(Context context)
    {
        this.parent = context;
        lists = new ArrayList<String>();

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(parent, R.layout.list_item1,
        R.id.text1);
    }

    public void setList(List<String> mlist)
    {
        this.lists.addAll(mlist);
    }

    public void doSort()
    {
        LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(parent);
        final View lview = factory.inflate(R.layout.sort_folders, null);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(parent);
        builder.setTitle("Sort Folders");
        builder.setView(lview);

        // ListView list = (ListView) lview.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        DragSortListView list2 = (DragSortListView) lview
        .findViewById(R.id.dragSortListView1);

        adapter.addAll(lists);
        // list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list2.setAdapter(adapter);

        // TODO: set buttons OK and CANCEL
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
            {
            }
        });

    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
        {
        }
    });

    final Dialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
    }

    private DragSortListView.DropListener onDrop = new DragSortListView.DropListener()
    {
    @Override
    public void drop(int from, int to)
    {
        String item = adapter.getItem(from);
        adapter.remove(item);
        adapter.insert(item, to);
    }
    };

    private DragSortListView.RemoveListener onRemove = new DragSortListView.RemoveListener()
    {
    @Override
    public void remove(int which)
    {
        adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(which));
    }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when using the DragSortListView inside a dialog fragment - turned out this only happened when the soft keyboard was visible when the fragment was being displayed. I'm not sure what the exact issue is, but I think something is either interfering with the focus or touch events the DragSortListView uses.

As a work around I hide the softkeyboard before displaying the fragment, this appears to solve the issue for now - see the below answer for the code on how to do this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7696791/1062909